# Why are additional query constraints in a "unique validation rule" built with a closure in Laravel Documentation?

Tags: laravel

I am referring to https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-unique, section **Adding Additional Where Clauses**.

In the example of the documentation, the additional query is returned within a closure:

```
'email' => Rule::unique('users')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('account_id', 1);
})
```

In my application I validate my request like this:

```
$request->validate([
    'display_name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'between:3,32',
        Rule::unique('devices')->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
        })
    ],
    // ...
]);
```

If I omit the closure, my code still seems to work as expected:

```
$request->validate([
    'display_name' => [
        'required',
        'string',
        'between:3,32',
        Rule::unique('devices')->where('user_id', auth()->id())
    ],
    // ...
]);
```

Is there a special reason for using a closure, like in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly doubt it makes a difference.  It looks like the `Rule::unique()` method is returning a Query\Builder object (the foundation for Eloquent) with a pre-generated base query of `SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM devices`. At that point, you're interacting with it as just a normal Builder object.  And `Builder::where()` offers either syntax you're using there.

When you supply a closure instead of field/(operator)/value arguments, the resulting query conditions get placed in parentheses.  So you can do things like `SELECT DISTINCT ? FROM devices WHERE ? OR (? AND ?)`.